# Tkinterr, Remove focus from execute button so app doesn't appear frozen

Tags: python, tkinter

I have seen similar questions that say you should simply have to set focus on another widget so the button won't appear frozen while the app runs. I want to eventually to build a progress bar, but for now I just want to click the run button and it release focus.

```
  ...
  main_menu = ttk.Frame(self.root)
  run_button = ttk.Button(main_menu, text="Run",
                            command=lambda self=self: self.execute_dummy())

  def execute_dummy(self):
    self.root.focus()
    #here I have a notebook also in the main frame, the third tab has an output buffer I want to switch too on execution
    self.main_notebook_frame.select(2)
    self.execute()

  def execute(self):
     #my class for handling the computation
     import gui_execute
     gui_execute()
```

The run button will eventually switch to the third tab in the notebook_frame, but only after the execution has completed. This presents a problem if there is a big input file. The run button looks "frozen" as the computation can take a couple of minutes to complete. Is there anyway I can switch to the notebook_frame third tab before execute? This to ensure the user that the app is not frozen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `after(time, function_name)` to execute function not directly in `execute_dummy()` by you but in main loop by system. Meanwhile program should change tabs.

```
self.root.after(100, self.execute) # 100ms = 0.1 second
```